# Making the result field editable or updatable within 5 minutes?

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on a project in C# to add two or more numbers and store the result in a database, actually it is adding marks of different subject papers together and after addition storing result in the database. 
Is there any way to allow the user to update or edit result within 5 minutes from the first entry of marks. After 5 minutes user will be unable to make any changing in it.

I wanted to know is there any way to implement this functionality?
and if yes then how to implement it in C# app or in SQL database?
I'm taking input through text fields.
Any good tutorial or program and any idea how to do it will be a great help.

Comment: this should be a constraint on the database - use a trigger to check the new update and query a history table to see when the row was originally entered, then throw the exception if it has been too long

Comment: Hi - have you managed to make any progress towards this on your own? This is quite a broad question, it may be easier for people to help if you ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options which all involve storing the timestamp along with the mark:

- Use a database trigger which checks if the difference to the stored timestamp is grater than 5min and stops the update
- Use a stored procedure you call from you app to update the data which checks for the time difference and refuses to update
- Perform the logic entirely in your C# app (load the timestamp, check the time difference and don't update if too large).

Which one is best depends on what database you use, what your setup is like how much experience you have, etc. - basically your business needs.

**Edit:** If you want to do it with a trigger then check [this codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server) article. It's about SqlServer 2000/2005 but should still work for 2008. Basically use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger for the update and rollback if your 5min constraint is violated otherwise issue the update.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisWue I would like to utilize your first option the database trigger.

Comment: I'm pretty new to sql and currently using SQL SERVER 2008 R2. Please can you guide me how to add new field for timestamp and how to use trigger to check if the  stored timestamp is greater than 5min and stops the update

Answer (score 1):

Store the modified date in the database.

1. when building the form for editting, if the modified date is
   older than the current date+expiry time, then render a read-only
   version of the page
2. when the user submits, if the modified date
       is older than the current date+expiry time, output an error.

Do #2, or #1 & #2, but don't do just #1.