# only retrieve record from sql database which have todays's date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm using SQL SERVER 2008 R2 to store data and C# web application to retrieve data and display it into gridview.

I have already stored data with different dates Now I want to show data daily on C# gridview according to date like : as today is 15 august and data having date as 15 august only populate the gridview.

I have created the datasource to populate the gridview which previously shows all the data irrespective of date:
code is as follows:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LoginConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Student]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now I want to just show only current date/todays date data as explained above. 
Please guide me how to write the sql command to achieve the above functionality. 
Table name is Student
Column Name is date stored as datetime

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "date" also contains time of day information, you have to strip it when comparing to current date:

```
WHERE CAST(Student.[Date] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: @Don can you please help me with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242994/making-the-result-field-editable-or-updatable-within-5-minutes

Answer (score 1):

Add your where clause to your select statement like this:

```
Where Cast(Student.Date As Date) = Cast(GetDate() As Date)
```

Edit: updated to use the cast instead of convert, and made it so it's only equal to today's date.

Comment: This may not be the "correct" way, but converting it to a varchar of lenght 10 will remove the timestamp, then convert it back to a DateTime (which will NOT have the timestamp anymore).

Comment: When I need to strip the time of day information, I always CAST(GetDate() AS DATE) - I have a suspicion that it's not as computationally expensive as converting back and forth to a character data type.

Comment: won't that return anything with a date greater than today's date?  i think the question asks for equality.

Comment: @Dan duly (sp?) noted. Thanks for that.

Comment: Hi ganders thanks I did the way as You suggest but still it is showing all the data of database but not of current date.

Comment: @chappoo since he is stripping the time portion he needs to get all greater date values. For example 8/15/2013 is actually 8/15/2013 12:00 AM. So if he does equality then it will not work for 8/15/2013 12:01 AM. The other option would be to strip the time from both date fields

Comment: @Dan how can I do it with GetDate()

Comment: @user2684131, Can you run profiler and see what the actual select statement says? There shouldn't be any issues since this is very straight-forward.

Comment: well, if the poster wants only records that match today only i don't think any of these are correct...  answer just posted @harper89 looks better

Comment: @user2684131 : WHERE CAST(datefield AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

Comment: @Dan its not working either showing an empty page. I'm tring to populate gridview with data from database.

Comment: @user2684131: Have you tried to browse the data for example in Management Studio to confirm that there actually are rows in the table that satisfy the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEDIFF

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where datefield = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

**EDIT**

I can not check at the moment but you can adjust and pull all dates between dates with a query like the one below.

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_NAMES 
where Date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 1)
and
Date >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

**EDIT**
Got around to testing. You can account for the timestamp differences you can convert the field to a VARCHAR and use the below query.

```
SELECT * FROM tablenames 
where CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Datecolumn) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE())
```

Comment: with this command its not showing any data and gridview on page

Comment: That is because your datefield is of type DateTime, which means it might also contain time-of-day information, which should be stripped. Check my answer elsewhere.

Comment: @user2684131 I cannot check the query at the moment but an example like the one in my edit should also work.

Comment: Actually you want to avoid `DATEDIFF` in the `WHERE` clause because of [this bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2481274). And an open-ended range should have `>= and <` not `< and >`.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand. Thanks overlooked that since I could not test atm. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better than casting the column as a date, IMHO, would be to use an open-ended range:

```
DECLARE @today DATE = GETDATE();

SELECT 
...
WHERE column >= @today AND column < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @today);
```

[Some background info on why you don't want to convert to string and why, in most cases, you want to avoid applying functions to columns](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).